# Getting 403 - Forbidden when Changing owner of Google Drive Folder using Service Account

Tags: google-drive-api

We are using the Google Drive API to perform certain file-related operations in our application. One of our use cases is to change particular folders owner.

I have return below code to perform this action

```
Permission permission = new Permission();

permission.setRole(Permission.OWNER.getRole());
permission.setType(Permission.OWNER.getType());
permission.setEmailAddress(email);

googleDrive.permissions()
  .create(fileId, permission)
  .setSendNotificationEmail(false)
  .setTransferOwnership(true)
  .execute();
```

When attempting to change the owner, we got an error from Google.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

We have checked errors listed here at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors. But, I didn't found any error with above detail.

When I have attempted to change ownership of a particular file using the same code, it worked fine.

Does anyone have any idea on what I'm missing or what might be the issue?

Also, the same works when I've used cURL to change folder ownership

```
curl POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]/permissions?transferOwnership=true' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"role":"owner","type":"user","emailAddress":"[EMAIL]"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Forbidden

Normally means that the user you are logged in with does not have the access themselves to do what you are trying to do.   So in order to change the owner i would suspect that you would need to have write access to that file or be the owner of the file itself.

For example i cant login and change the owner on a file that you own I dont have enough access to the file.

You may also want to check the scope you are authenticating with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I'm performing the operation as an owner of that folder only. As I said, I'm able to use the same code to change the permission of a particular file resided in the same folder. But, it didn't work for the folder.

Note that I've permissions at folder (parent) level, not at the file level.

Comment: Are all of the files in the folder already updated to this new owner?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. But, yes, when I add new contributor (not owner) or viewer to the folder, all files in the folder gets the same permission.

Comment: Thats news to me who ever uploads the file is normal the owner of the file regardless of what directory the file is placed into.   I guess they must have changed something since I last checked. Either way the error is the same forbidden means that the user you are logged in with cant change the permissions as they are not owner

Comment: I found the cause. As you can see in the question above that I've set `sendNotificationEmail=false`. This shouldn't be set to false when changing owner for `user` or `group`. 

But, it's strange that `google-drive-sdk` hasn't reported the proper error message.